# Why bower is not downloading js files during ember new or bower install/update

Tags: ember.js, bower

After running ember new app, the app does not load because bower failed to download
all required dependencies from github.

Answer (score 3):

- run the command bower cache clean
- remove bower_components dir
- run bower install

Comment: I ran into this same issue. Bower install would get all files but the javascript. This is what finally did it.